# CentOS 6.5 - Plesk Onyx 17.0.17 - PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/apc.so'

Tags: server, centos6, plesk

I'm receiving the following error when checking the PHP version on our VPS Server running CentOS 6.5 (Final) with Plesk Onyx 17.0.17:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/apc.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/apc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Aug 11 2016 20:33:53) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd.
```

I've also run the following yum info php command which gives me:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.bytemark.co.uk
 * epel: mirror.bytemark.co.uk
 * extras: mirrors.coreix.net
 * updates: mirrors.coreix.net
Installed Packages
Name        : php
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 5.3.3
Release     : 48.el6_8
Size        : 3.5 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : updates
Summary     : PHP scripting language for creating dynamic web sites
URL         : http://www.php.net/
License     : PHP
Description : PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language. PHP attempts to make
            : it easy for developers to write dynamically generated webpages.
            : PHP also offers built-in database integration for several
            : commercial and non-commercial database management systems, so
            : writing a database-enabled webpage with PHP is fairly simple. The
            : most common use of PHP coding is probably as a replacement for CGI
            : scripts.
            : 
            : The php package contains the module which adds support for the PHP
            : language to Apache HTTP Server.
```

We're currently setting up a staging site to run Magento 2 and the above error is causing issues with trying to reindex any of the Magento Index Management services and installing theme/extensions.

I'm not sure what extra information would be of use so do let me know of any commands to run to generate some more useful information.

I am new to server type work so please do bear with me and go into as much detail as you can.

Comment: Are you sure that your magento site works on this PHP 5.3.3? Maybe I'm wrong but I've think that Magento requires PHP 5.4+.

Comment: Magento 2.1 works ok PHP 5.6 as a minimum now. The hosting for the staging site is running PHP 7.0.13. The server remains on PHP 5.3.3 as a recommendation I read online [link](https://kb.layershift.com/check-php-version-on-plesk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that somewhere in PHP's configs in `/etc/php.d/` defined loading of APC extension by string like `extension = apc.so`

it may be file:
    /etc/php.d/apc.ini

But file `apc.so` doesn't exists in default extensions folder `/usr/lib64/php/modules/`

You can:

- disable loading of this extension
- or check existiens of `/usr/lib64/php/modules/apc.so`
- or reinstall package `php-pecl-apc.x86_64`

  ```
  # rpm -qf /usr/lib64/php/modules/apc.so # determines package of file
  php-pecl-apc-3.1.9-2.el6.x86_64

  # yum remove php-pecl-apc.x86_64
  # yum install php-pecl-apc.x86_64
  ```

For executing PHP scripts in CLI with system PHP you just need to install php-cli package: `yum install php-cli`

In case you still need another PHP version you can try Plesk's PHP in folder /opt/plesk/php/ (like `/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php`)

In case you don't see anything in `/opt/plesk/php/` you can install additional PHP versions with Plesk Installer.

Comment: Perfect that worked for me! Thank you @oleg. That said I'm now encountering another problem. I didn't realise that the CLI can use a different version of PHP. From a google search I can see that PHP 5.3.3 isn't capable of running the PHP file over CLI and need to use a different version of PHP. I believe PHP 5.6 is what I need to be using. Could you advise on how to use a different PHP version on CLI?

Comment: @user387729 Actually, PHP 5.3 is ok for executing in CLI, you just need to install CLI package: yum install php-cli

Comment: @user387729  In case you still need another PHP version you can try Plesk's PHP in folder /opt/plesk/php/ (like /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php) In case you don't see them you can install additional PHP versions with Plesk Installer.

Comment: After some more routing around I found an article which gave me the following code to switch the CLI PHP Version to 5.6: <br/> _echo  'PATH=/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin:$PATH'  >>  .bashrc  &&  source.bashrc_<br/>. Thanks for you help!